# Color Specification class in c# is giving me error : The non-generic type-or-method 'identifier' cannot be used with type arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I am learning design patterns in C#, so I wrote a class which filters the products by color (enum). I used interfaces `ISpecification` and `IFilter` which take `T` as a generic type.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
public interface ISpecification<T>
{
    public bool IsSatisfied(T t);
}

public interface IFilter<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> Filter(IEnumerable<T> items, ISpecification<T> specification);
 }

 public class ColorSpecification : ISpecification<Product>
 {
     private Color color;

     public ColorSpecification(Color color)
     {
         this.color = color;
     }

     public bool IsSatisfied(Product product)
     {
         return product.Color == color;
     }
}

/// <summary>
/// new way, implements open close design pattern
/// </summary>
public class BetterFilter : IFilter<Product>
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Filter(IEnumerable<Product> items, ISpecification<Product> specification)
    {
        foreach (var i in items)
        {
            if (specification.IsSatisfied(i)) 
                yield return i;
        }
    }
}
    
public static void Main(string[] args)
{   
    var bf = new BetterFilter();
    var cs = new ColorSpecification<Product>(Color.Green);

    foreach (var p in bf.Filter(products, cs))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Green products(new) {p.Name}");
    }
}
```

When I instantiate a new class for `ColorSpecification` which determines whether an item of type `Product` satisfies the specification, I am getting an error on this line

```
var cs = new ColorSpecification<Product>(Color.Green);
```

> The non-generic type-or-method 'ColorSpecification ' cannot be used with type arguments

How can I solve this error?